# How to get a expected result by comparing array using a specific value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement

let say I have some class that store object name, which define every object in the project

```
let arrays = [“obj1”, “obj2”, “obj3”, “obj4”]
```

so I have another class which used for receiving the input from the view controller
which return an “Int” that refer to obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 let assume it as 1 2 3 4 to called an array respectively

```
struct getIndex {
    let objIndex: Int
}
```

in view controller I need to print an item in the array

i.e. name: obj1 etc. etc.

but since the view controller return 1 2 3 4 which refer to every items in the array
so I want the if-condition to print only wanted item ie. obj1 and 3 not obj2 and obj4

ie. if the view controller return 2 or 4 it won’t do anything

but if it return 1 or 3 it will call the obj1 and 3 and print it as expected

something like

```
if someclass.getindex == something I don't know for obj1 and 3 {
    print(String(format: "%@", objectName)
}
```

Comment: "it return error on if condition line" What error? You are comparing a Int with an array of String?

Comment: What is someclasss? Is it an object? Add more code please.

Comment: @Larme no actually, I want the condition where when value1 in the viewController get a value from another function which is "Int" to print only array no. 1 and 3 not 2 ie. print 0001 and 0003 even though another function return "Int" for no.2 string

Comment: @RomanPodymov yes, it is used to store value to call an array for another class

Comment: @JameS it is really so hard to understand what problem you need to solve. Add more code please. We will check your full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you're looking for:

```
if ["0001", "0003"].map{Int($0)!}.contains(someclass.value1) {
    print(someclass.value1)
    print(someclass.value2)
}
```

I'm sure there's a better way to resolve your potential problem though...